# FlutterApp via BLE to ESP32

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm a Flutter beginner, and I'm trying to integrate my ESP32 with my Flutter-made app. In the app, I'm using the 'flutter_blue_plus' package as my BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) toolkit. However, I'm encountering an issue where my ESP32 development board is not receiving the information sent from the app. I'm getting the following error message: "PlatformException (PlatformException(writeCharacteristic, The WRITE property is not supported by this BLE characteristic, null, null))".

I've attempted to modify the BLE implementation on my ESP32. I changed the data type used for receiving data from String (previously using getValue()) to uint8_t* (using getData()), but I'm still encountering the same error.

Comment: Have you tested the ESP32 using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? What does it say about your characteristic? Is it writable?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan 
Yes, I've successfully connected to my ESP32 using nRF Connect APP, and I can send values to the ESP32 without any issues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the relevant parts of your source code as well as a screenshot of nRF Connect showing the characteristics and their UUIDs